# How to make a stacked (tidy) dataframe where the index (indices) are filled in each row?

Tags: dataframe, export-to-excel, series, multi-index, pandas-styles

I needed to take a wide, MutiIndex dataframe and stack it into Tidy for another program to chart it. I got that solved [in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74553654/how-do-you-update-column-headers-to-change-a-single-index-dataframe-into-a-multi). However, the final exported file has merged cells for the stacked indices. I need each index repeated in the row so that the other program doesn't read the merged portion as "null".

We have a group of Products, Year, Colors, and Sizes for the indices and the Sales numbers as the data. After the final stack, the dataframe looks like this:

```
# Minimum Working Example of incoming data in wide format
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
colhead = ["Small Black", "Small White", "Small Brown", "Medium Black", "Medium White", "Medium Brown", "Large Black", "Large White", "Large Brown"]
rowhead = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['sofa','table','chair'],[2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]])
df_mix = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size=15,9)), index=rowhead, columns=colhead)

# Reindex by list and use .names to label dataframe hierarchy
hierarch1 = ["Small", "Small", "Small", "Medium", "Medium", "Medium", "Large", "Large", "Large"]
hierarch2 = ["Black", "White", "Brown", "Black", "White", "Brown", "Black", "White", "Brown"]
df_mixfix = df_mix
df_mixfix.columns = [hierarch1, hierarch2]
df_mixfix.columns.names = ['Size', 'Color']
df_mixfix.index.names = ['Product', 'Year']

# Stack for tidy data
stk = df_mixfix.stack()
df_stk = stk.stack()
print(df_stk)
```

```
Product  Year  Color  Size  
sofa     2011  Black  Large     1
                      Medium    5
                      Small     1
               Brown  Large     9
                      Medium    4
                               ..
chair    2015  Brown  Medium    6
                      Small     5
               White  Large     8
                      Medium    1
                      Small     6
Length: 135, dtype: int32
```

Note that some additional tables are created, where the MultiIndex is regrouped by year first, then by product.

Regardless of the grouping, What I need it to look like is this, where each of the grouped-by rows is filled with the index, so that when I run the export to excel **(this is the problem here: because it looks like above, not below)**, the tidy data will not be merged:

```
Product  Year  Color  Size  
sofa     2011  Black  Large     1
sofa     2011  Black  Medium    5
sofa     2011  Black  Small     1
sofa     2011  Brown  Large     9
sofa     2011  Brown  Medium    4
                               ..
chair    2015  Brown  Medium    6
chair    2015  Brown  Small     5
chair    2015  White  Large     8
chair    2015  White  Medium    1
chair    2015  White  Small     6
```

**What I have tried** is able to get the displays in Jupyter notebook to not look sparse, but the export to Excel still ends up merged. I had to update pandas to 1.5.2 then used the following:

```
pd.set_option("display.multi_sparse", False) # for output display
pd.set_option("styler.sparse.index", False) # fills in rows
with pd.ExcelWriter('Tidy.xlsx') as writer:
    df_stk.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sales') #still has merged cells
```

**How do I get each explicit level element in a hierarchical key for each row in the Excel?**

Comment: I used this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html#options) and this [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html) to get the Jupyter notebook display filled in... I just can't get the export to not be sparse!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! While the examples weren't helpful, buried in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) was the info that I just needed to add the parameter `merge_cells=False`

so the whole thing inside the writer is:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Tidy.xlsx') as writer:
    df_stk.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sales', merge_cells=False) # Fully Tidy data!
```

Note: this will un-sparse all hierarchical merges.